# Preference Maximizing Choice Rule

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, economics

Definition: A **Choice Rule** is a function $ C: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X) $ such that $ C(B) \subset B, $ $\forall B \in \mathcal{P} (X) $ and $ C(B) \neq \emptyset $ if $ B \neq \emptyset $

The interpretation is that $C(B)$ is the set of options that may be chosen from the menu of $B$ options.

Let $C^*(B)$ be the class of choice rules such that $C^*(B)=C^*(B,\succsim)=\{x\in B : \forall y \in B, x \succsim y \}$

This is called the Preference Maximizing Choice Rule

And define $ \displaystyle S^* = \cap_{x \in B} \{y \in B: y \succsim x \} $

Show $S^* = C^*(B)$

Tips and hints how to show this please, I am confused how the x's and y's may change position going from one side to the other.

Comment: "Let $C^*(B)$ be the class of choice rules such that $C^*(B)=C^*(B,\succsim)=\{x\in B : \forall y \in B, x \succsim y \}$".This bit is extremely confusing. Don't you just mean "Let $C^*(B)$ be $\{x\in B : \forall y \in B, x \succsim y \}$"?

Comment: Well yes, I think what I wrote provides more information and calls it a class of choice rules too; can you help with the proof?

Comment: Just use the definitions.

For instance to prove that $S^* \subseteq C^*(B)$, take $s\in S^*$. By definition of $\bigcap$, this means that $\forall x\in B\left(s\in \left\{z\in B\colon z\succsim x\right\}\right)$.

You wish to prove that $s\in C^*(B)$, i.e., $s\in B$ and $\forall y \in B(s \succsim y)$. So take $y\in B$. Using the hypothesis (with $y$ in place of $x$) yields $s\in \left\{z\in B\colon z\succsim y\right\}$, that is, $s\in B$ and $s\succsim y$, as required. By the way, when it comes right down to it, this is just an elementary set theory exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I kindof understand ... I'll read this over and over till I do(:

Comment: Why do you replace y with z?  And why can you replace x with y?

Comment: Why I can make those substitutions is due to the variables being bound. I wrote a partial answer below in which I avoid that as much as possible. I hope it's enough for you to understand.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you, but I still don't quite understand the fundamental reason why we are allowed to substitute variables.  If we were considering only one of these sets I would, as the variables are arbitrary.  But we are considering two sets with their own definitions.  So like in algebra where if we apply something to one side of an equation we must likewise apply it to the otherside (unless it is an identity of course).  So if we replace variables in one set, why don't we need to replace the same varibles in the other set at the same time?

Comment: I sort of see where you're coming from, but I'm having trouble finding a way of explaining it to you without getting too technical. I'll try anyway. Note that $C^*(B)$ can be understood as the set of elements of $B$ which are preferred over all other elements of $B$. There is no mention of variables here. Now you want to prove that $S^*$ equals this set. I suggest you read the relevant sections on bound variables on [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995) by [D. J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: Okay!  I will buy this as an e-textbook at your suggestion :D it looks great, I'm having trouble making the transition to proofs so this looks splendid.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the chosen variables are causing some confusion, so allow me to rewrite the problem slightly to dissipate this problem.

> Define $C^*(B)=\{y\in B\colon \forall x \in B(y\succsim x)\}$ (note that this is exactly the same set as in your question, despite $x$ and $y$ having swapped their roles) and $S^*=\bigcap\limits_{x\in B}\left(\{y\in B\colon y\succsim x\}\right)$.
>
> Prove that $C^*(B)=S^*$

Start by noting that $\forall s\left(s\in S^*\iff \forall x\in B\left(s\in \{y\in B\colon y\succsim x\}\right)\right)$

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #000000]{C^*(B)\subseteq S^*}$

Let $y\in C^*(B)$. One gets $y\in B$ and $\color{blue}{\forall x\in B(y\succsim x)}$.

(Remember that the goal is to prove that $\forall x\in B\left(y\in \{y\in B\colon y\succsim x\}\right)$).

Take $x\in B$. Due to the blue hypothesis above, $y\succsim x$ follows. But this means that $y\in \{y\in B\colon y\succsim x\}$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, this means that $y\in S^*$.

I'll leave the other inclusion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the second answer helps clear somethings for me, I'll try and answer the other direction with my comments to see how well I understand this.

$\boldsymbol{\Leftarrow C^*(B) \subseteq S^*}$

Let $s \in C^*(B)$ Then $s \in \{z \in B: \forall y \in B, z \succsim y \}$ *This says that z are all of the elements of B that are preferred to all of the y elements in B, and s is one such of these elements equivalent to z.*

We want to prove $s \in S^*$ which can be done by showing $s \in \cap_{y \in B} \{ z \in B: z \succsim y \}$ i.e. $\forall y \in B, s \in B$ and $s \succsim y.$  *Here we replaced y with z, and x with y from the definition of $S^*$.*

Take $y \in B$ by the hypothesis this gives us $s \in B$ and $\forall y \in B, s \succsim y$, as desired.  *Please explain what "take" means, is it like consider the arbitrary element y in an arbitrary set B?*

Comment: Yes, the meaning of "take" or "let" here is exactly what you mention in the last sentence. I would make a small correction at the end. Take $y \in B$ by the hypothesis this gives us $s \in B$ and $s \succsim y$. Since $y$ was an arbitrary element of $B$ this means that $s\in B$ and $\forall y \in B, s \succsim y$, as desired.

Comment: Great I see, this helps even more!  I was completely lost and I think I'm starting to understand this.  Thank you so much for all your help and patience @GitGud !!!!! <3 :D ^_^